# Why is my input box overlapping its parent container?

Tags: html, css

this is my code:

```
<section className="createTodo-box"> // parent
    <div className="createTodo-inside"> // child
       <Input
         value={this.state.text}
         style={{ width: '200px' }}
         onChange={(e) => this.setState({ text: e.target.value })}
         type='text'
         placeholder='What needs to be done?'
       />
     <Button onClick={() => this._confirm()} type="primary"> Create </Button>
   </div> 
</section>
```

my css:

```
.createTodo-box {
    border: solid #C3C3C3 1px;
    width: 200px;
    margin: 25px;
    padding: 15px;
}
.createTodo-inside {
    padding: 15px;
}
```

I tried using padding of 15px on the .createTodo-inside but my Input still overlaps on the right? [image].

Comment: input with 200+ .createTodo-inside  padding 15, then overlap to createTodo-box

Comment: @ÁlvaroTouzón thanks, I wanted it 200px, how do I make it work?

Comment: .createTodo-box {width:230px;} adding padding right  and left of .createTodo-inside

Comment: Please increase width of .createTodo-box by 30 px.

Comment: There is already 15px padding for `createTodo-box` and 200px width for `input`. So inorder to fix the overlapping, Give `230px` width for the `createTodo-box` or decrease the width of `input` by `30px`

Comment: Actually you need to increase by 60px `.createTodo-box { width: 260px }`. You have an inner `div.createTodo-inside` also with 15px padding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `.createTodo-inside` class inherits a `width:100%` You need to adjust the padding size to the parent `width` no matter how wide is your parent. You can get this behavior using `box-sizing`:

```
.createTodo-inside {
  padding: 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Those new guys who found this type of overlapping problem, always remember that you have to apply `box-sizing: border-box;` in the universal selector `*{}` or anywhere where you want to initially prevent overlapping. then you should do some research about box model. you will get your answer when you will know about box model.